# Can't get a PDF package(knp-snappy with wrapper from barrydvh) for laravel running

Tags: laravel, pdf

How can i install this package (https://packagist.org/packages/barryvdh/laravel-snappy)?
I am on Windows using Xampp. I followed the step and when i try to call from my controller.

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.invoice', $data);
return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');
```

it is not being recognized.

Clear step by step to fresh laravel 5 install will be very much appreciated. Thanks before

Comment: What's the actual error you receive? Have you tried `\PDF::loadView('pdf.invoice', $data);`?

Answer (score 0):

### You can use

```
use Barryvdh\Snappy\Facades\SnappyPdf as PDF;
```

Answer (score -1):

Have added it to the service provider  app/config/app.php

```
'Barryvdh\Snappy\ServiceProvider',
```

And facades further down:

```
'PDF' => 'Barryvdh\Snappy\Facades\SnappyPdf',
'Image' => 'Barryvdh\Snappy\Facades\SnappyImage',
```

then in your controller?:

```
Use PDF;
```

And what is in your $data?

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy

Comment: actually when i also try to use this syntax
return PDF::loadFile('http://www.github.com')->stream('github.pdf');
the PDF also mark as unknown class, and the autocomplete shows no completion for the facade i register